# Scala CompiledScript reuse

Tags: scala

I am trying to use Scala ScriptEngine (2.11) to run Scala script in Java. 
The script uses the bindings provided to the engine.
Script is used multiple times with different bindings.
For this, I am using CompiledScript.

The script runs fine for the first time and uses the bindings. 
But, when the same CompiledScript is rerun using new bindings, the result does not change.
What I observed is that the script actually does not run the second time. It just uses the stored engine state.

The following is the code snippet:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("scala");
    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("firstVal", 209);
    bindings.put("secondVal", 30);
    bindings.put("sumUtil", new Sum());
    CompiledScript script = ((Compilable)engine).compile(
        "var sum = sumUtil.asInstanceOf[com.myutils.Sum]\n"+
        "var firstInt = firstVal.asInstanceOf[Integer]\n"+
        "var secondInt = secondVal.asInstanceOf[Integer]\n"+
        "sum.add(firstInt, secondInt)\n"    
        );          
    Integer res1 = (Integer) script.eval(bindings);
    System.out.println("Result 1: "+res1);
    bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("firstVal", 2);
    bindings.put("secondVal", 3);
    Integer res2 = (Integer) script.eval(bindings);
    System.out.println("Result 2: "+res2);
```

The output is:

firstVal: Object = 209
secondVal: Object = 30
sumUtil: Object = com.myutils.Sum@71136646
Result 1: 239
firstVal: Object = 2
secondVal: Object = 3
Result 2: 239

The expectation is that Result 2 is "5" instead of 239.
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Thanks in advance